# Iterator Pattern - Circular Reference

Tags: c++, iterator, circular-dependency

Is there anyway to avoid this circular reference? I cant use foward declaration, because I am accessing methods of PositionBlock inside PositionBlockIterator...

I know that i can create an interface to PositionBlock, and then use it inside PositionBlockIterator (polymorphism). But is there another way?

```
class PositionBlockIterator{
private:
   PositionBlock *posBlock;
public:
     PositionBlockIterator(PositionBlock *posBlock_){
         posBlock = posBlock_;
     }
     /* functions to iterate over positionblock, using posBlock->... */
}

class PositionBlock
{
public:
   PositionBlockIterator * createIterator(){
       return PositionBlockIterator(this);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class PositionBlock;
class PositionBlockIterator;

class PositionBlockIterator{
    private:
        PositionBlock *posBlock;

    public:
        PositionBlockIterator(PositionBlock *posBlock_);
};

class PositionBlock {
    public:
        PositionBlockIterator * createIterator();
};

PositionBlockIterator::PositionBlockIterator(PositionBlock *posBlock_) {
    posBlock = posBlock_;
}

PositionBlockIterator * PositionBlock::createIterator(){
    return new PositionBlockIterator(this);
}
```

You can also see this compiling [here](http://ideone.com/qIiIGO). I'd also recommend moving the implementations of the two functions into separate `*.cpp` files.

Comment: It looks like Rubber's issue is specifically with the `/* functions... */` that they are not showing us.  :)  (I'm speculating)

Comment: @DrewDormann: This same pattern will work on that as well though.

Comment: This is how you do it, but the answer would be better if you explained *why*.

Answer (score 1):

A nested class should work in this situation (not tested).

```
class PositionBlock{
public:
  class Iterator{
  private:
     PositionBlock *posBlock;
  public:
    Iterator(PositionBlock *posBlock_){
       posBlock = posBlock_;
    }
    /* functions to iterate over positionblock, using posBlock->... */
  };

  Iterator * createIterator(){
     return new Iterator(this);
  }
};
```